# SHLoadImageFile API not working

Tags: c++, windows-ce

As  mentioned in the title I am facing problem with SHLoadImageFile API.
I am trying to load a series of captured images one by one and trying to retrieve the respective image properties. The API is  not returning a valid handle for an image of higher resolution, for the rest of images (with decreasing resolution) its working fine.
Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong???
Here is my how my code looks

// Code to capture image

```
hBmp = SHLoadImageFile(szFilePath);      //szFilePath- refers to loaction of the image
if(!hbmp)
//error msg

current_bmp.Attach(hBmp);  
current_bmp.GetBitmap(&hBmpInfo);
```

//code to copy image width and height to a local variable.

As soon as the location of image of higher resolution is sent as parameter,the control entersto if block and displays error msg.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me.  It looks like you diagnosed the problem correctly, that Windows CE can't handle the size of image you tried to load.

Comment: So is there any alternate method to load the image(here a jpeg image) and extract image properties?

Comment: I haven't tried this in Windows CE but it might work: http://www.xdp.it/cximage.htm

Answer (score -1):

I remember that the SHLoadImageFile() API will be failed when try to load an image that exec

Comment: ... what kind of images 'exec'?